# Sql server express edition deployment

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, deployment, setup-project, setup-deployment

i have one window application developed in .net framework 4.0 and Sql server 2008 R2. I want to create set up for the same.

Is there any way possible that the set up can install SQL server too on the machine for those user who don't have sql server on the machine?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Sql server you prerequisites tools or create bootstrap installer for doing this.

These includes some configuration files settings or some other stuff..
Check more about this on MSDN

[Embedding SQL Server 2008 Express in an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Check this link  also

[Install SQL Server (Express) with your Application](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/install-sql-server-express-with-your-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed MsSQL Express in the custom applications. Have a look at MSDN article -  [Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://Embedding%20SQL%20Server%202008%20Express%20in%20an%20Application).